# mysql copy catalogue

Tags: mysql

My server's mysql settings got wiped out.  I'd like to move a single catalogue (wordpress install, fyi) to another server where I have mysql running.  I did an scp of the catalogue ("cf") under /var/mysql/ over to my new server.  Setup a user, granted all privs, everything showed up fine.  I can browse the tables and their contents in my GUI.  The only problem is: when I try to update a row on the new server, I get an error "Table 'wp_options' is read only".  What's the best way to fix?  Thanks.

Comment: I can add new tables and edit their structure and contents.  Just can't update existing tables' rows.

Comment: did: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to thartman@"%" IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass' WITH GRANT OPTION;

still can't update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

common causes for this error:

1. data files have the wrong permissions. have you checked who the owner is and what the permissions are?
2. another mysql server instance is also using the same files and has them locked at the file system level.
3. the tables are corrupted. try running REPAIR on the tables.

Comment: yeah. just did a chmod 777 for now to make sure that's not the issue.  also tried a chown mysql:mysql on it.

Answer (score 1):

finally solved it:

```
sudo chown -R _mysql:wheel cf
```

restarted and now it works.  (Leopard Server)